# How do I access the BIOS after setting a Supervisor User password on my Toshiba Tecra A10?

Tags: bios, toshiba-laptop

I've set a supervisor password on a Tecra A10 laptop, but now I can't choose the boot device or enter the BIOS as supervisor.

I **do** know the supervisor password however I don't get the prompt to enter it. Do you have to use a different keyboard shortcut to access the BIOS with the Supervisor user on boot?

Comment: The problem has been solved. You need to hold the Insert key down while powering the laptop on. You will then get prompted for the supervisor password.

Comment: Hi @MrHrappstead, good to hear you solved your problem! Would you care to add it as an answer? I've added it as a Community Wiki answer for now, ping me and I'll remove it when you post your answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to hold the Insert key down while powering the laptop on. You will then get prompted for the supervisor password.

Comment: You Sir, saved my day! (couldn't find that information in any piece of manual I was looking up on Toshiba's web pages)

Answer (score 0):

From the OP:

> The problem has been solved. You need to hold the Insert key down while powering the laptop on. You will then get prompted for the supervisor password